# Prove that $(n+2)^4 + 16\cdot4^n$ is composite number for every $n$ natural number?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that $\,(n+2)^4 + 16\cdot4^n\,$ is composite number for every $\,n\,$ natural number ?

I end up in a conclusion proving for $n$-odd and $n$-even but, I’m not sure if it's correct, is there any other possible solution for this ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Seems like treating odd and even $n$ separately is best. $n$ even, after all, is quite obvious.

Comment: With $m=n+2$ this is $m^4+4^m$.

Comment: There's a general factorization $x^4+4y^4=(x^2-2xy+2y^2)(x^2+2xy+2y^2)$ which will work for the odd case.